# Determine whether a function is coercive or not.

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, coercive

$f(x,y) = \frac{x^4}{x^2+1} + |y| $

I want to see if the given function is coercive or not.

My questions is that I'm stuck on how to transform the function into $(x^2+y^2)$ form. I need to convert into that form to show that $f(x,y) \to \infty$ as  $\|(x,y) \| \to \infty$.

Any hints are appreciated! Thank you!

### EDIT

Although I didn't find what L is yet (copper.hat suggested this idea) but based on copper.hat's hint I got an idea that $\frac{x^4}{1+x^2}$ goes infinity as $x$ goes infinity. Likewise, $|y|$ goes infinity as $y$ goes infinity. Then if $\sqrt(x^2 + y^2)$ goes infinity, I can say that the given function also does because either $x$ or $y$ should increase for  $\sqrt(x^2 + y^2)$  to be infinity, which implies that $f(x,y)$ goes infinity because either term $\frac{x^4}{x^2+1}$ or $|y|$ will go infinity.

Is this logic reasonable?

Comment: Find some $L$ such that if $|x|>L$ then ${x^4 \over 1+x^2} > |x|$.

Comment: @copper.hat thank you for the hint. I edited my post based on your hint. Could you comment on my idea, please?

Comment: No, your idea is fine, but it needs to made formal, which it is not. Why don't you start with my first suggestion.